# Macbook a1181 stopped working and commands doesnt work after installing windows

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows

I installed windows 10 in my macbook a1181 model but then my mac Os has stopped working even i could not switch to it. But i mistakenly made clean the entire hdd without having backup and tried to internet recovery. after that nothings shows even not any command works. It  looks like windows. Help!

[image]

Comment: A1181 isn't specific enough to identify the precise model, it could be any Macbook from 2006 to 09. However, none of these models will start to Internet Recovery & most of them won't boot from a USB, so try this… At the boot chimes hold Cmd/R & see what appears. You may see as many as 3 'disks' to choose from. Let us know what you do see & we can go to the next step.

Comment: Actually after the windows installation the hdd has been formatted with a windows bootable drive and mistakenly deleted the entire hdd to unallowcated..  After that command +r , command+s is not working..  When i hold this and starts nothings shows.   It redirects to the screen which i have shared

Comment: Then you're going to need either the original installer disks, or take it to an Apple Store where they will do it for free. btw, the drive cannot be entirely unallocated, otherwise you wouldn't get the "Windows can't find anything" message. That is not any part of macOS. Try holding Opt at boot, see if you get anything different.

Comment: Model is mid 2009

Comment: 09 might just boot from USB, if you can get an installer made up. [needs another Mac]

Comment: When hoding option.. No bootable drive shows cobtains mac os but windows bootable usb shows as efi and in the hdd theres no os installed so a drive shows named windows but if i click this again same massage

Comment: Another mac in the sense should i try through terminal?

Comment: Sorry, this is just getting more & more confused. I now can't tell what you've done or with what, or what you ended up with; it's all a bit stream of consciousness. We cannot see over your shoulder, you must tell us - preferably in your original question not as a string of comments, **exactly** what you did & what you ended up with. For instance you now just mentioned some kind of Windows USB… you didn't clarify if you have access to another Mac..

Answer (score 2):

This message is not from Microsoft software that should have been installed in the MBR. Most likely you did not correctly install Windows 10. Apple does not support Windows 10 on your Mac. This does not mean Windows 10 can not be installed. However, adding more information on how you installed Windows 10 would be helpful. For example, the I would at least have the following questions.

Which version of Windows 10 are you using?

- Currently, an updated Windows 10 is released twice a year.
- Most users install the Windows Home or Windows Pro. Many others exist.
- There are 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

Where did you acquire the installation media?

- There are ISO files that can be downloaded.
- There are ISO files and flash drives that can be created after downloading the create installation media on a machine running Windows.
- You can burn a bootable DVD from an Windows ISO file.
- You can create a bootable flash drive from a mounted Windows ISO file.
- Some Macs can create the Windows 10 installation flash drive using the Boot Camp Assistant.

Where did you acquire the Windows Support Software (Boot Camp Support Software)?

- Did you download the Software using Boot Camp Assistant.
- You can download Windows 7 versions from an Apple website.
- You can use Brigadier or manually directly from Apple servers.
- You could not not used any Windows Support Software.

Did your installation involve the use of refit, rEFInd or GRUB?

Did you BIOS or EFI boot the Windows 10 installation media?

Did you install Windows 10 to BIOS or EFI boot?

Did you use the GUI or CLI (or both) to install Windows 10?

How did you install Windows 10?

- One method is to modify the Boot Camp Assistant.
- You can use the DVD drive.
- Some Macs can use a USB flash drive.
- There are many methods where a virtual machine is employed.
- There are methods where you first boot from the Windows 10 installation files stored on the internal drive.

How did you bless the Mac?

- This is done automatically when using the Boot Camp Assistant.
- In some cases, this can be done from OS X by using the `bless` command.
- This can be done from OS X Recover by using the `bless` command.
- On some Macs, you can do this from Windows after installing the Windows Support Software.
- On some Macs, this can be done from the Mac Startup Manager.

> Note: In some cases, knowing the version of OS X would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the hard drive / SSD and doing a complete erase, format and partition on a different machine.

Once done then reinstall the mac os suitable for that machine and follow with a reinstall of the windows system you want. You could do this on the separate machine or back in your own machine.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest it looks like you might need to get a completely new hard drive that works with the computer that also has mac installed on it then go through the process of installing windows on it again  .

Comment:  is there any other resetting mode?

Comment: I don't believe so, it looks like the partition or drives the system is allocated to isn't working which could mean your hard drive has done its time.

Comment: If it is then system might recognise other bootable usb..  But when i plugged in bootable usb contains mac it doesnt shows but it recognising when i plugged an efi windows bootable drive